# Soft Question:Is the following a Paradox?

Tags: logic, soft-question

Can the statement: "I swear by God that I will never swear" be regarded as a variant of the Paradox of Self-Reference like the one "I am a liar"?

Comment: No. "Will never" implies future action, whereas the current oath is a present action. This is the same thing as saying "I'll never have another drink after this one." Alternatively, you could say, "I swear by God that I will have never sworn," indicating that in the future a condition will have been met, but then you'll just be a liar. Ultimately "swearing by God" is not a condition that induces impossibility.

Comment: Of course no kind of swearing induces any impossibility! We are only talking of the inherent logical structure of sentences here

Comment: The question is probably better suited at the English Language & Usage StackExchange. There is no inherent logical construction here, just semantics.

Comment: This isn't a question about English. It's ultimately more appropriate for math, but probably moreso philosophy until the problem is more formally stated. English is being used to convey the problem, but it's ultimately a problem about some kind of structure in the statement and whether there is a problem under some kind of evaluation.  I.e. whether some function is well-defined.  The issue here is that it isn't clear what that function is because we don't have a solid context.

Comment: This is clearly a paradox, but it is not of the Liar type. A paradox is a statement that appears to contradict itself. This clearly is the case. We can assign a truth value to this statement. The semantics of the statement might be ambiguous but once you fix an interpretation the statement becomes true or false. The statement can be simplified to "I will never type this sentence." The truth value is false. I just typed it. If we don't remove the "will" part then it might become true if you happen to never swear. The structure of the liar paradox is given by self reference to its truth value. T

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it is paradoxical for a few reasons.

1) This has some time aspect to it, like Arkamis discussed in his comment.  Saying you *will* do something doesn't necessarily include this particular instant / sentence.  So "will never swear" doesn't interfere with swearing right this second.  If you want a formal context to consider this in, try some kind of modal or temporal logic.

2) It's possible the first and second usage of "swear" are different in this sentence.  That is, the first could be "to make an oath", and the second could be "to use foul language".  If this is the case, then it's clear no self-reference is going on.  This is English rather than a formal language, and the semantics is a bit strange.

3) Notice that in the liar paradox, the logical you-can't-even-evaluate-the-truth problem is caused by making a statement which *directly* asserts its own falsehood. Both "I am a liar" or even better "I always lie" lead to a paradox upon evaluation.  This is because you bounce from the statement to the person and *directly back to the statement* because liars "tell falsehoods".  It seems (at least to me) like you can't do that with "promises", "swearing", etc.  At least not with this particular sentence.  Maybe a more complicated one like "I swear I'm the kind of person that ..."

It's already problematic to evaluate your sentence as true or false.  A formal answer requires deciding how *you* want to evaluate things of the form "[person] promise(s) [whatever]" and when they are true or false.

But, my guess is that in any reasonable formalization of this, you can get out of problems with this statement "I swear by God that I will never swear", even if you believe this is problematic because they're currently swearing, by concluding it is "false" or more naturally "the person is a liar" and stopping there.  There doesn't seem to be anything in the meaning of "I swear" which *directly* impacts truth or falsehood of this particular statement and leads to a logical problem. "I swear it is true" is not the same as "it is true", if you get what I mean.

Comment: I will mention that this last is an example of a performative if and only if this is EL&U.

Comment: You shouldn't say it is not paradoxical because it is. Liar paradox is not the only type of paradox. In Quine's classification (depending on how the phrase semantic is interpreted) this would be a falsidical paradox.

Comment: @ABC I think the OP didn't have that sort of paradox in mind. After checking Quine's classification, I think he's asking if it's an antimony. I argue it isn't.  Moreover, it can't be a falsidical paradox, since there is no demonstration, and hence no fallacious one.  It's a single statement, and presumably the OP is asking whether it yields a paradox under some correct investigation.

Comment: A falsidical paradox doesn't have to be a proof. It is just a paradox that has truth value false. An incorrect proof is in particular a statement, a statement that is false. Yes, the OP was only asking if it was a variant of the Liar, which you answer correctly as no. But it is a paradox.